# Dialed in and unplugged in formal English

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, idioms, expressions

Actually, I kind of understand the meanings of "dialed in" and "unplugged" in the following context, but it strikes me that they are a little informal. 
I am intrigued to know what is their formal alternatives? 
If I may could you possibly let me know how they are uttered in formal contexts. That would definitely clear up the ambiguities.

- I check my phone far too much a day. I read a lot of things on the internet and I check things. I know that I'm too much **dialed in** and I need sometimes to be **unplugged**. I have to work on **unplugging**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/dialled-in) offers a definition for "dialed in" of "exhibiting total concentration on and mastery of the task in hand." In this context, the "total concentration" meaning makes sense; the speaker feels they are too narrowly focused on internet content. [This in-depth treatment at Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/phone-it-in-vs-dialed-in) offers more perspective and history. A different but common meaning is "perfectly adjusted in minute detail," as in "It took me awhile to get the hang of this golf club, but I'm starting to get my swing **dialed in**."

One of the definitions that [Merriam-Webster offers for **unplugged**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unplug) is "to temporarily refrain from using electronic devices (such as computers or smartphones)." This may perhaps be derived from the use of "[unplugged](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unplugged)" to mean a musical performance emphasizing acoustic rather than electric instruments, popularized in the 1990s.

Yes, both usages are a bit informal, even if they're not "slang"; they would be acceptable in business-casual conversation but not academic writing. One could choose many replacements; these are not exhaustive lists:

- **"dialed in":** focused, obsessed, engaged, fixated, myopic. (One could mention "tunnel vision," but this might be a bit informal again.)
- **unplug**: If we mean specifically "spend time without electronic devices," the best replacement is to say something like this directly: "I know that I'm too fixated on internet content and I need sometimes to go without electronic devices for a while." Other general terms could include: disengage, simplify, relax, release.